# How do I update a table's field to be SUM of the field and a different (related) table's field with Sqlite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I need to update `sets.weight` to be equal to `workout.body_weight + sets.weight` for each set.

I have a table `sets` representing sets of a lift, which belongs to a liftgroup, which belongs to a workout (workout has liftgroups, and each liftgroup has lifts, and each lift has sets). `workout.body_weight` is my weight on the day I lifted.

`sets.weight` is the weight I lifted for that particular set.

For weighted pullups I was storing just the weight I was hanging from my body in `sets.weight`. I want to update this field to be the current value *plus* my `workouts.body_weight` on that day.

I've tried a number of suggestions I found in similar questions on SO, but get syntax errors when trying to copy. Possibly this is because Sqlite has a more limited featureset and those answers were for MySQL or PostgreSQL or something.

I've managed to *select* the relevant data:

```sql
SELECT
  *
FROM
  sets as T1
  inner join (
    SELECT
      workouts.body_weight + sets.weight as new_weight,
      sets.id as id
    FROM
      sets
      LEFT JOIN lifts ON sets.lift_id = lifts.id
      LEFT JOIN lift_groups ON lifts.lift_group_id = lift_groups.id
      LEFT JOIN workouts ON workouts.id = lift_groups.workout_id
    WHERE
      lifts.lift_id = 5
  ) T2 ON T1.id = T2.id
```

This outputs `id`, `lift_id`, `reps`, `reps_goal`, `weight`, `new_weight`, `id` fields (first 5 are all the fields in `sets`

All the `LEFT JOIN`s are there to connect a set to the corresponding parent workout just so I can retrieve the workout.body_weight

How can I change this to accomplish what amounts basically to `UPDATE sets SET weight = new_weight` ?

Comment: Can you add the relevant table descriptions?

Comment: I think everything relevant is in my OP. I provided the col names for sets entity, that workout.body_weight exists, and that all the tables "in between" in the hierarchy have a FK from child_table.parent_table_id to parent_table.id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up working:

```sql
UPDATE
  sets
SET
  weight = (
    SELECT
      sets.weight + workouts.body_weight as new_weight
    FROM
      sets T2
      INNER JOIN lifts on sets.lift_id = lifts.id
      INNER JOIN lift_groups ON lifts.lift_group_id = lift_groups.id
      INNER JOIN workouts on workouts.id = lift_groups.workout_id
    WHERE
      lifts.lift_id = 5
      AND sets.id = T2.id
  )
where
  EXISTS (
    SELECT
      sets.weight + workouts.body_weight as new_weight
    FROM
      sets T2
      INNER JOIN lifts on sets.lift_id = lifts.id
      INNER JOIN lift_groups ON lifts.lift_group_id = lift_groups.id
      INNER JOIN workouts on workouts.id = lift_groups.workout_id
    WHERE
      lifts.lift_id = 5
      AND sets.id = T2.id
  )
```

What was throwing me was that in sqlite I cannot begin a query with `UPDATE tablename AS alias . . .`. Instead, I have to omit the alias, but for the parenthetical SELECT statement I can use one, and then refer to the two tables as tablename and tablealias. Which you can see I did in the snippet.

The first and second parenthetical SELECTS are equivalent. The first generates the new value I want to update to. This gets fed into the UPDATE part. The WHERE EXISTS is just a safeguard to make sure a weight doesn't get set to null if no rows are returned by the SELECT.